# SMTP Host Issue in China

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I have an issue regarding smtp using codeigniter email library. It works fine with smtp.gmail.com but I have to use vpn in this case. I found other solutions like smtp.exmail.qq.com, smtp.mail.yahoo.com or smtp.sina.com but when you send the form typing your email in email field its being sent only with the email you provided in smtp user. Further please look at my code and screen shot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrJ63.png):

```
         //get the form data
         $name = $this->input->post('name');
         $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
         $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
         $message = $this->input->post('message');

         //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
         $to_email = 
         'info@sample.com';

         //configure email settings
         $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
         $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.exmail.qq.com'; 
         //'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
         $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
         $config['smtp_user'] = 'myemail@exmail.qq.com';
         $config['smtp_pass'] = 'my password';
         $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
         $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
         $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
         $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
         //$this->load->library('email', $config);
         $this->email->initialize($config);                        

         //send mail
         $this->email->from($from_email, $name);
         $this->email->to($to_email);
         $this->email->subject($subject);
         $this->email->message($message);
```

Comment: I solved the issue after having trouble for many days.
If we assign same value to smtp_user=email1@anymail.com and email_from=email1@anymail.com then the issue is being solved.